# printing characters of string from the end to the beginning using range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

i want it to print every character in the string but from the end to the beginning of the string (inverted),it does not show any syntax error so whats the problem . i tried using print i in range(end,beginning) method but it does not show any output .
but it does not say its a syntax error or anything

```
s="John000Doe000123"
for i in range(len(s),0) :
 print (s[i])
```

Comment: See, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp  to eread about `range`.

Comment: does not show an example like mine

Comment: `range` takes a 3rd parameter - the `step`. Set it to `-1`. You can also do `for c in reversed("hello"): print(c)`. There are other options....

Comment: But it explains everything. Just read it and then apply to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for c in s[::-1]:
    print(c)
```

Comment: it works but can u explain to me how u did it

Comment: `[::-1]` on a string or list reverses it and you just iterate as usual,

which means `[<start_index>, <stop_index>, <step>]`

Comment: You should rename `i` to something like `char` as you are not indexing.